# Is there a fish way of doing zsh's noglob builtin?

Tags: fish

From https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshmisc :

```
noglob
Filename generation (globbing) is not performed on any of the words.
```

zsh example:

```
$ ls /*
  <lots of output>
$ noglob ls /*
ls: cannot access '/*': No such file or directory
$ ls "/*"
ls: cannot access '/*': No such file or directory
```

In fish, this works with quotes:

```
$ ls "/*"
ls: cannot access '/*': No such file or directory
```

Is it possible in fish to do the same thing without requiring quotes?

Comment: This is a good example of a "feature" that should never have been implemented and why I stopped using zsh long ago.

Comment: Absolutely agree.  There are some features I often *think* I miss from zsh, but when I see the Fish team's reasoning behind why they did it differently, it almost always makes more sense.

Comment: @snapshoe What's your ultimate goal with the `noglob` behavior?  I'm guessing it's something more subtle than the command-line usage you demonstrated itself.

Comment: I frequently do 'find' commands like `find /path -name "*.ext"`, and I shortened that with a zsh noglob alias to simply do `findf /path/*.ext` which finds all files in all subdirs under path, including those in /path. I've used '**' wildcards in fish. I'm perfectly open to the answer being "No", and I'm not a great fan of noglob either. But it is nice to have a function or alias with the noglob in it when I don't want to have to put quotes around args all the time. I'm just getting familiar with with fish recently, and this is one small thing I came across.

Comment: Makes sense - The `alias` case *is* greatly simplified by having `noglob` precede the command.  Do you use additional `find` arguments with `findf` or always as above?  Can you provide your entire alias here?  I think I *might* have a fish alternative.

Comment: I've had [these lines](http://ix.io/2Lbo) in my .zshrc for years. Probably buggy. Getting different results between my zsh alias+function and fish `find /path**.ext` and other incantations led me to post this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Original answer:* Regarding `noglob` behavior itself, I'm fairly certain the answer is "No", per [this Github issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3504).

*Edit/Update:*  But given the use-case you describe in the comments, there may be another way to avoid typing the quotes, albeit nowhere near as straightforward as `noglob`.

For the sake of keeping this as simple as possible, I deviated slightly from your example in the comments.  According to that example, you use `noglob` in zsh to create an alias so that:

`findf /path/*.ext` maps to `find /path -name "*.ext"`

I went with using a space to separate the path and the name into two distinct parameters:

`findf /path *.ext` maps to `find /path -name "*.ext"`

Well, sort of - At least that's what you would type.  The workaround in this case is to get fish to add the surrounding quotes for you automatically when you type an argument to `findf` with a `*` wildcard.

To do that, set up three functions (two of them are just one-liners), all in `~/.config/fish/functions`:

*findf.fish:*

```
function findf --description 'alias findf=find {path} -name {name}'
    find $argv[1..-2] -name $argv[-1]
end
```

Pretty straightforward - Just passes the last argument to `findf` as the `-name` argument to `find`.

Then the real workhorse.  *findf_binding.fish*:

```
function findf_binding 
    commandline -i '*'
    set -l tokens (commandline -bo)
    if test (count $tokens) -gt 0
    and [ $tokens[1] = "findf" ]
        set -l currentToken (commandline -t)
        if not contains "\"" (string split "" $currentToken)
            set -l replaceToken "\""$currentToken"\""
            set -l cursorPos (commandline --cursor)
            commandline -t $replaceToken
            commandline --cursor (math $cursorPos+1)
        end
    end
end
```

This basically boils down to *"If `*` is pressed, and the line starts with* `findf`*, and argument with the `*` isn't quoted already, then quote it and move the cursor after the `*`."*

Finally, bind the `*` to the `findf_binding` in *fish_user_key_bindings.fish*:

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
    bind '*' findf_binding
end
```

Full disclosure - This is my first keybinding script in fish.  It's a fish feature that I've been wanting to learn/try out for a while now, and I saw this as a good opportunity.  As a result, though, there are undoubtedly some corner cases that I missed, and style or syntax improvements that could be made.

For instance, as a known limitation, if you ever want to use wildcards to match multiple paths (e.g. `findf path* *.yaml`) this binding will erroneously add quotes to the path component as well.

But hopefully this gets you close to what you are looking for, or at least puts you on the right track to tweak it or write your own.

Comment: I'm comfortable with the original "No" answer. Binding to '\*' is an interesting idea I hadn't considered, and seems to address replacing noglob. I agree there seems like there would be corner cases, and I do appreciate the huge effort. I will experiment with binding to '\*' and see where it leads me.